Can a holomorphic function = its power series (about a point) globally?
Suppose that $\Omega \subset \mathbb{C}$ is the union of two circles that intersect (but don't overlap), each with centers $z_0, z_1$ and common radius $r$. Suppose $f$ is holomorphic on $\Omega$. Thus, we have two power series on distinct regions:
On $B_r(z_0), f = \sum a_n(z- z_0)^n$.
On $B_r(z_1), f = \sum b_n(z- z_1)^n$.
But since these two regions intersect, so that $\sum a_n(z- z_0)^n = \sum b_n(z- z_1)^n$ on an open set of the complex plane, are we able to say that $f = \sum a_n(z- z_0)^n = \sum b_n(z- z_1)^n$ on $\Omega$?
Here is my reasoning:

First of all, we don't even have both of the power series already defined on $\Omega$.

But suppose that we were able to "define" them by whatever arbitrary means. But then, although they are equal on $B_r(z_0) \cap B_r(z_1)$, each of them is holomorphic on a different region, i.e., $\sum a_n(z- z_0)^n \subset \mathcal{H}(B_r(z_0))$ and $\sum b_n(z- z_0)^n \subset \mathcal{H}(B_r(z_1))$. Thus, we cannot apply our usual analytic continuation principle (which would require both to be holomorphic on all of $\Omega$, which we don't have a priori).


Is there anything else interesting to be said here? Do we ever have the above capability, so that, for ex., we can say that $f = $ a (fixed) local power series expansion everywhere on $\Omega$, even if arbitrarily sized balls around that point aren't in $\Omega$?
I've seen a prior post where the above doesn't hold, but I'm interested in cases that it does (assuming $\Omega$ is connected and what not).

The power series can be extended as far as you'd like until you hit another pole.
